# reference datatype javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, what is the difference in applying a toString() method to the primitive datatype, number like this

```
var myString = myNumber.toString();
```

and applying the same toString() method by creating a reference datatype equivalent, the Number class like this

```
var numberObject = new Number(myNumber);
var myString = numberObject.toString();
```

Comment: The primitive is converted temporarily into an object to call the method, then the object is gone

Answer (score 1):

In a chrome console if you type:

```
new Number(10).toString === (10).toString
```

It returns true, so I suppose there is no difference between the two since both functions refers to the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent and give the same result.

JavaScript allows to create objects without using `new` keyword.

For example, you may create an array using `new Array(1, 2, 3)`, but you may also use the shorter syntax `[1, 2, 3]`.

Use shorter notations (`(123).toString()`, `"hello ".trim()`, `[1, 2, 3].reverse()`, etc.) whenever possible. They are explicit enough, so there is no need to pass by a verbose `new <Type>()` notation.

Comment: i know that both of them give the same result but when and why should i prefer one method over the other?

Comment: @user1463541: use shorter notations (`(123).toString()`, `"hello ".trim()`, `[1, 2, 3].reverse()`, etc.) whenever possible. They are explicit enough, so there is no need to pass by a `new <Type>()` notation.